# Bloomberg API SDK not compatible with Anaconda Python

Tags: python, api, anaconda, blpapi

I spent hours yesterday trying to get the blapi up and running and finally gave in and emailed their support, this is the response:

> "Unfortunately our BLPAPI SDKs are not compatible with the Anaconda
>   distribution of Python. That Python is built using GCC, and it is not
>   capable of loading DLLs that were built using Microsoft Visual Studio;
>   our DLLS were built with MSVS.
>
> This means you'll need to use the Python distribution from Python.org,
>   which is also built with MSVS."

I cannot download the normal Python (from Python.org) due to security constraints, but for some reason I can do Anaconda.  Honestly it's preferable for me anyhow because I don't want to mess with having to download 15 diff packages I need afterwards.

Does anybody have any idea if it is even possible to work around this?  It seems ridiculous that Bloomberg would force you to use the straight distribution and then have to go download all the packages you want individually by making this incompatible with GCC builds.

Comment: If there's no source distribution of the BLPAPI you could compile on your own (which the support response would probably have suggested), the statement is correct - you could of course use any other MSVS compiled python distribution (not sure there's another one out there...).

Comment: what about Enthought?  How is that one compiled (didn't see it in a quick search)

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. The Anaconda Python and Python extension modules are built using Visual Studio (2008 for Python 2 and 2010 for Python 3, the same as the Python installers from python.org).

Comment: Guess I'll have to take it up with Bloomberg then...Since you work at Continuum I'm much more inclined to believe you than them ;)  Unfortunately they aren't much help.

Comment: What errors are you getting when installing it? Did you check the box to make Anaconda the default Python when you installed it?

Comment: wall of text and the last string is : “error: command 'C:\\Users\\frb\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1”.

Comment: Is there a line in the wall of text with an error message?

Comment: This could be a simple mis-configuration.   Why is gcc.bat trying to be run.    I believe Anaconda on Windows is setup to use mingw to build extensions by default (which does build compatible DLLS in most cases by the way).   We would be happy to get the SDK and debug the problem.

Comment: Try `conda remove libpython`. That will cause Python's distutils to not use gcc when building extension modules.

Comment: The fun continues -- I tried `conda remove libypthon` and then ran setup.py again -- now I get `error: Unable to find vcarsall.bat`

Comment: So I tried installing the Visual C++ 2008 compiler, still got same error.  Then read that I need setuptools >=6.0 (i have 5.8), tried installing that but pip won't work for me (timeout)... and I can't use the powershell commands they listed either.  `> (Invoke-WebRequest https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py).Content | python - --user` again prob related to security issues.  Lastly I tried `python setup.py build -- compiler=mingw32` and got the same gcc.bat error.  I think it's time to throw in the towel. Overstringent IT: 1, Me:0

Comment: Unfortunately I was the one who provided the misinformation to the OP; the binary installers of the BLPAPI Python SDK work just fine with the current Anaconda Python 2.x distribution. There is no need to build the API wrapper from source, and I did not test that against Anaconda Python so I cannot verify whether it will or won't work (yet).